# terminate called after throwing an instance of 'char const*' error

Tags: c++

I'm new to programming and when I try to use the exceptions handling I got an error in codeblock 16:01

terminate called after throwing an instance of 'char const*'

this is the error.

could someone help me with this error ,  I tried to reset the IDE to default , but didn't work

the code is

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <stdexcept>

using namespace std;

double sqrt(double num)
{
    if(num < 0)
        throw "Negative number is not allowed";
    double x = pow(num,0.5);
    return x;
}

int main()
{
    double x;
    cout <<"Enter a number : ";
    cin  >> x;
    double num;

    try
    {
        num = sqrt(x);
    }
    catch(const char *text)
    {
        cout << "ERROR : "<<text<<endl;
        return 1;
    }

    cout <<"Square root of "<< num <<" is : "<<num;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Create a [mcve].

Comment: @NeilButterworth `throw "Negative number is not allowed";`

Comment: @Barmar I guess He is picking up the std::sqrt function, which doesn't throw.

Comment: `sqrt` is a c library function, you're redefining it leading to undefined behaviour. In VC at least it's defined as `noexcept` for c++.

Comment: @NeilButterworth Then why is he getting an error saying that a string was thrown?

Comment: I'm really surprised it doesn't error about the function call being ambiguous.

Comment: It might be related to `std::sqrt` (or `sqrt` from `<cmath>` - not sure if it is put into `std`) function being included, since if I try to compile such code, I get warning `'sqrt': function assumed not to throw an exception but does`.

Comment: @user657267 What?  They didn't put it in `std` so there is no UB AFAIK

Comment: @NathanOliver Implementations are free to define c names in the global namespace even when including c-prefixed files such as `cmath`.

Comment: @user657267 No `nothrow` for `sqrt`.

Comment: @liliscent Like I said, VC at least defines it with `noexcept`.

Comment: @loody A bit late in the day to ask which compiler and version this is?

Comment: @user657267 Shouldn't the redefinition be a hard error and not UB?

Comment: Does not throw for me because the user defined `sqrt()` is not being called. It calls `std::sqrt()` which has been brought into the current context because of `using namespace std;`

Comment: @NathanOliver Depends on whether the header only declares or defines the function, the former would result in an ODR violation which doesn't require an error.

Comment: @user657267 On my clang Mac OS X, with `-O0`, no call to `sqrt` at all, just an assembly instruction, which suggests its inline definition.

Answer (score 2):

Regardless of the implementation details that resulted in the error, your program has undefined behaviour because you're using a reserved function signature from the C library.

http://eel.is/c++draft/reserved.names#2

> If a program declares or defines a name in a context where it is
>   reserved, other than as explicitly allowed by this Clause, its
>   behavior is undefined.

http://eel.is/c++draft/reserved.names#extern.names-4

> Each function signature from the C standard library declared with
>   external linkage is reserved to the implementation for use as a
>   function signature with both `extern "C"` and `extern "C++"` linkage,
>   or as a name of namespace scope in the global namespace.

In your specific instance it looks like your compiler's library defines `sqrt` as `noexcept`, but ends up using the definition you provide which does throw, resulting in a call to `terminate`.